# How to parameterize a pyramid with a square base?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I wanted to parameterize and draw a pyramid with a square base. The base was parameterized as a function of t
, getting:

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{t, 0, 0}, {t, 0, 4}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{4, t - 4, 0}, {t, 4, 8}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{12 - t, 4, 0}, {t, 8, 12}], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{0, 16 - t, 0}, {t, 12, 16}], PlotRange -> Full]
```

The pyramid would be lifted from a point (2,2,8)
, but when I draw the line between that vertex and one of the base lines, nothing works, and it separates all the graphs. Is there a better way for me to do this?

Comment: Do you really need the parametrization, or do you just want to draw a pyramid? In latter, you can use [`Pyramid`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pyramid.html). Also, instead of `ParametricPlot3D`, you can simply use [`Line`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Line.html).

Comment: I actually need the parametrization. I already used the Line command to do that but it's not really what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Show[
{ParametricPlot3D[{0, 0, 0} t + (1 - t) {4, 0, 0}, {t, 0, 1}],
  ParametricPlot3D[{4, 0, 0} t + (1 - t) {4, 4, 0}, {t, 0, 1}],
  ParametricPlot3D[{4, 4, 0} t + (1 - t) {0, 4, 0}, {t, 0, 1}],
  ParametricPlot3D[{0, 4, 0} t + (1 - t) {0, 0, 0}, {t, 0, 1}],
  ParametricPlot3D[{0, 0, 0} t + (1 - t) {2, 2, 6}, {t, 0, 1}],
  ParametricPlot3D[{4, 0, 0} t + (1 - t) {2, 2, 6}, {t, 0, 1}],
  ParametricPlot3D[{0, 4, 0} t + (1 - t) {2, 2, 6}, {t, 0, 1}],
  ParametricPlot3D[{4, 4, 0} t + (1 - t) {2, 2, 6}, {t, 0, 1}]
},  PlotRange -> Full]
```

You forgot the list bracket of objects. The line parametrization is done conventionally by the convex combination of two points with factors t amd 1-t for t in the unit interval

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for the help!

Comment: `Show` works with or without the curly brackets, as illustrated in the documentation.